# Run the code tensorflow 1.15 in tensorflow 2.7

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

I want to run code that uses tensorflow == 1.15 but has tensorflow 2.7 installed on my system. According to Tensorflow at this address https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrate_tf2, I use the following lines so that I can run the code without changing in tensorflow 2.7:

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()

But I do not know what to do instead of the following lines in my code!
Because, according to Tensorflow "You can still run unmodified TF1.x code (except for contrib) against TF2 binary installations"

```
    l2_reg = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=self.beta)
    xavier = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Tf.contrib is deprecated in Tensorflow 2.x

Replace

```
tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer
```

with

```
tf.compat.v1.keras.regularizers.l2
```

Replace

```
tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer
```

With

```
tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.glorot_normal
```